Thuja Arborvitae Trees, 2 yr
I planted 10 Thuja fast growing Arborvitae trees 2 yr. ago. They are about 3-4 ft tall now. Just the other day I noticed very small light green balls on 4 of them. I don't know if this is normal or could it be diseased ? I live in Raleigh area of NC 27592

Fast-growing arbs don't exist. You'll get 12 - maybe in a good year, 18 - inches of new growth per year.

Please post a photo

That would be the fruit or "seed cone"
https://www.ontario.ca/page/eastern-white-cedar
describes them thus

Fruit
Cones grow in clumps of 5 or 6 pairs (7 to 12 millimetres long).

And has pictures which won't link directly, so go look at them there.
